# What is the meaning of movabs in gas/x86 AT&T syntax?

Tags: x86, amd64

I just found a strange instruction by assembling (with `gas`) and disassembling (with `objdump`) on a `amd64` architecture.

The original `amd64` assembly code is:

```
mov 0x89abcdef, %al
```

And, after `gas` compiled it (I am using the following command line: `gcc -m64 -march=i686 -c -o myobjectfile myassemblycode.s`), `objdump` gives the following code:

```
a0 df ce ab 89 00 00    movabs 0x89abcdef, %al
```

My problem is that I cannot find any `movabs`, nor `movab` in the Intel assembly manual (not even a `mova` instruction).

So, I am dreaming ? What is the meaning of this instruction ? My guess is that it is a quirks from the GNU binutils, but I am not sure of it.

PS: I checked precisely the spelling of this instruction, so it is NOT a `movaps` instruction for sure.

Comment: I think the first 5 bytes is `a0 ef cd ab 89`, not `a0 df ce ab 89`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19415184/load-from-a-64-bit-address-into-other-register-than-rax

Comment: Also see [When was the MOVABS instruction introduced?](http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/6540/5853)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's the [official documentation for `gas`](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dVariations.html), quoting the relevant section:

> In AT&T syntax the size of memory operands is determined from the last
>   character of the instruction mnemonic. Mnemonic suffixes of `b`, `w`,
>   `l` and `q` specify byte (8-bit), word (16-bit), long (32-bit) and
>   quadruple word (64-bit) memory references. Intel syntax accomplishes
>   this by prefixing memory operands (not the instruction mnemonics) with
>   `byte ptr`, `word ptr`, `dword ptr` and `qword ptr`. Thus, Intel `mov
>   al, byte ptr foo` is `movb foo, %al` in AT&T syntax.
>
> In 64-bit code, `movabs` can be used to encode the `mov` instruction
>   with the 64-bit displacement or immediate operand.

Particularly read the last sentence.

**Note:** Found via Google operator `inurl`, searching for `movabs inurl:sourceware.org/binutils/`.

Comment: I looked at the gas manual but I did not find the right section. Thanks a lot 
0xC0000022L ! :-)

Comment: How can you move a 32 bit number into al?

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: well you can only with losses, but this has nothing to do with my answer or the question, so you better ask it as a new question.

Comment: What's interesting, gdb gives me `48 b8 <imm64>` bytes as `movabs rax, <imm64>` even in `disassembly-flavor=intel`.

Answer (score 9):

movabs is used for absolute data moves, to either load an arbitrary 64-bit constant into a register or to load data in a register from a 64-bit address.

Source: http://www.ucw.cz/~hubicka/papers/amd64/node1.html

Answer (score 8):

If you find yourself often deciphering AT&T syntax x86/x64 assembler, Solaris manuals may be of help: [x86 Assembly Language Reference Manual](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54851/index.html) .

Comment: good downloadable reference  thanks igorsk for the link

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that GAS translates

```
movq $0x80000000, %rax
```

into

```
movabs 0x80000000, %rax
```

But values smaller than 0x80000000 movement is not translated into `movabs`.
That is, `movq $0x7fffffff, $rbx` is NOT translated into `movabs $0x7fffffff, %rbx`. You can verify with `disas` disassemble command within GDB.

Maybe the reason is that `$0x80000000` is over the signed positive number range of 32 bit and needs to be translated into 64-bit integer.  For the reason, GAS translates such larger number into  64-bit long integer and therefore uses `movabsq` instruction instead of `movq` instruction whose immediate source is limited to 32 bit constant.

Comment: this is incorrect `movq $0x80000000, %rax` moves the immediate 0x80000000 into rax whereas `movabs 0x80000000, %rax` loads the quadword at address 0x80000000 to rax

Answer (score 1):

### Initialization of local variables with movabs

Yes this instruction should move absolute hardcoded data embedded into instruction itself into register,
or data from absolute address. But I got into this instruction only recently when I wanted to know where constant data for initialization of local variables are because I didnt find them in *.rodata* ELF section.

So basically GCC uses this instruction to initialize automatic variables on stack!

Lets dive into code to find out how this instruction is used.
As we see in this code example  we have local variable *test* initialized:

[image]

We know that local variables are put in stack and I was interested to know
where and how local variables get initialized.

When we dump .text section with objdump we see that this constant *0x41414141414141* is realy embedded in the code itself:

```
000000000000116c <get_message2>:
116c:   f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64 
1170:   55                      push   %rbp
1171:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
1174:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
1178:   64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
117f:   00 00 
1181:   48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
1185:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
1187:   48 b8 41 41 41 41 41    movabs $0x41414141414141,%rax
118e:   41 41 00
```

---

As we see disassembled function and register content from GDB:

[image]

So when we look at code we see that this string *test*, in HEX notation *0x0x41414141414141* is hardcoded in **movabs** instruction, and is put in **rax** register, and then content of **rax** register is put on address in **rbp** minus offset 0x10:

```
   0x000055555555517d <+27>:    movabs $0x41414141414141,%rax
   0x0000555555555187 <+37>:    mov    %rax,-0x10(%rbp)
```

So this local string will be placed on address **0x7fffffffdde0** - **0x10**
We see that this local string is placed in stack frame of function
on address **0x7fffffffddd0**, and this we see when we dump the stack:

```
(gdb) x/16gx $sp
0x7fffffffddd0: 0x0041414141414141  0x6a8574f1d6812b00
0x7fffffffdde0: 0x00007fffffffddf0  0x000055555555515b
0x7fffffffddf0: 0x0000000000000001  0x00007ffff7daad90
```

So we ended with initialized local string on a stack just as we expected.