# When was the MOVABS instruction introduced?

Tags: x86, amd64, gas

When trying to write an instruction set analysis tool for disassembled code (https://superuser.com/a/832440/384221) I have found opcode MOVABS which was not included in my opcode source database (Shirk's `gas.vim` file) and I am not sure in which architecture it has been introduced.

According to [What is the meaning of movabs in gas/x86 AT&T syntax?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/2627/9891) and other sources it seems that the instruction has been introduced before 64-bit architectures. But was it with i686 or earlier?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`movabs` is just a GAS-specific way to enforce encoding a 64-bit memory offset or immediate. It's still the same standard [`MOV` opcode](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOV.html).

I'm not sure where you got the notion that it was introduced before x64, it's obviously not correct. For example, the [Solaris x86 manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36859/eoizm.html#scrolltoc) mentions: "movabs valid only under –m64".

Comment: Oh, so it is the same as nopw and nopl, thank you. By the way, do you know if I could find anywhere these GAS-specific opcodes?

Answer (score 6):

As Igor mentioned, it's GAS specific.

```
git log --reverse -Smovabs
```

tells us that it was introduced [in 2000 commit c0d8940](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=commitdiff;h=c0d8940f87f55d81d2a68b9333e494b48c1a49d3;hp=087f563c287b29cb52d78072d019764cf78124c8) and:

```
git tag --contains c0d8940
```

says that it was present as early as `binutils-2_11`.